# Self-built Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, mlp

I have been trying to build a simple neural network myself (3 layers) to predict the MNIST dataset. I referenced some codes online and wrote some parts my own, the code runs without any errors, but something is wrong with the learning process. The trained network always gives me wrong predictions, one or two classes always have very high probability no matter what I pass in as input. I tried to figure out the problem but not making any progress in a few days. Could anyone give me some hints where I did wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})
def init_setup():
    #three layers perception
    w1=np.random.randn(10,784)-0.8
    b1=np.random.rand(10,1)-0.8
    #second layer
    w2=np.random.randn(10,10)-0.8
    b2=np.random.randn(10,1)-0.8
    #third layer
    w3=np.random.randn(10,10)-0.8
    b3=np.random.randn(10,1)-0.8
    return w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3
def activate(A):
    # use ReLU function as the activation function
    Z=np.maximum(0,A)
    return Z
def softmax(Z):
    return np.exp(Z)/np.sum(np.exp(Z))

def forward_propagation(A,w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3):
    # input A :(784,1)-> A1: (10,1) ->A2: (10,1) -> prob: (10,1)
    z1=w1@A+b1
    A1=activate(z1)
    z2=w2@A1+b2
    A2=activate(z2)
    z3=w3@A2+b3
    prob=softmax(z3)

    return z1,A1,z2,A2,z3,prob
def one_hot(Y:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:

    one_hot=np.zeros((10, 1)).astype(int)
    
    one_hot[Y]=1
    return one_hot

def back_propagation(A,z1,A1:np.ndarray,z2,A2:np.ndarray,z3,prob,w1,w2:np.ndarray,w3,Y:np.ndarray,lr:float):

    m=1/Y.size

    dz3=prob-Y 

    dw3=m*dz3@A2.T

    db3= dz3
    dz2=ReLU_deriv(z2)*w3.T@dz3
    dw2 =  dz2@A1.T
    db2 =  dz2
    dz1=ReLU_deriv(z1)*w2.T@dz2
    dw1 = dz1@A.T
    db1 =  dz1
    return db1,dw1,dw2,db2,dw3,db3
def ReLU_deriv(Z):
    Z[Z>0]=1
    Z[Z<=0]=0
    return Z 
def step(lr,w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3,dw1,db1,dw2,db2,dw3,db3):
    w1 = w1 - lr * dw1

    b1 = b1 - lr * db1    
    w2 = w2 - lr * dw2  
    b2 = b2 - lr * db2
    w3 = w3 - lr * dw3 
    b3 = b3 - lr * db3       
    return w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3
```

put functions together

```
def learn():
    lr=0.5
    dir=r'C:\Users\Desktop\MNIST - JPG - training\{}'
    w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3=init_setup()
    for e in range(10):
        if e%3 == 0:
            lr=lr/10
        for num in range(10):
            Y=one_hot(num)
            # print(Y)
            path=dir.format(str(num))
            for i in os.listdir(path):
                img=Image.open(path+'\\'+i)
                A=np.asarray(img)
                A=A.reshape(-1,1) 
                z1,A1,z2,A2,z3,prob=forward_propagation(A,w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3)
                # print('loss='+str(np.sum(np.abs(Y-prob))))
                db1,dw1,dw2,db2,dw3,db3=back_propagation(A,z1,A1,z2,A2,z3,prob,w1,w2,w3,Y,lr)
                w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3=step(lr,w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3,dw1,db1,dw2,db2,dw3,db3)
    return  w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3
optimize_params=learn()
w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3=optimize_params
img=Image.open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\MNIST - JPG - training\2\5.jpg')
A=np.asarray(img)
A=A.reshape(-1,1)
z1,A1,z2,A2,z3,prob=forward_propagation(A,w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3)
print(prob)
print(np.argmax(prob))
```

After running the learn function, the network gave me something like this

```
>>>[[0.040939]
    [0.048695]
    [0.048555]
    [0.054962]
    [0.060614]
    [0.066957]
    [0.086470]
    [0.117370]
    [0.163163]
    [0.312274]]
>>>9
```

The result is obviously wrong, the true label should really be 2, but as we see on the prob, class 2 has an extremely low value, thus I believe there must be something wrong in the learning process. But I have no clue at all, can someone please give me some hints?

Comment: better keep code in separated functions - it will be more readable and you may test some functions separately. It would be simpler if you would use smaller network with smaller data - so you could calculate all on paper and compare it with calculations in code

Comment: are you sure you use correct indexes for elements? Python start indexes as `0` but you may start classes at `1` - and it needs to add `1` to get correct class.

Comment: @furas Yea, the Y label starts with 0 too, so the correct prediction result is supposed to be 2 in this case.

Comment: but do you have `class 0`? if you start with `class 1` then you have to add `1` to result to get correct class.

Comment: BTW: you should use spaces around `=` and after `,` , and put some empty lines to make code more readable. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @furas, Hi furas, yes there is class 0, thank you very much for the suggestion I will keep that in mind when coding next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only trains on labels 0 and 1

```
for num in range(2):
```

So there is no way for your model to "know" about any other labels.

---

Now your model is trained in a very ordered way, and thus has a bias towards **last** classes. As these are the last ones it saw during training. You should **shuffle** your training data in each epoch and not feed the network class-wise

Comment: Sorry I made a typo when writing this post, It was 10 but I wrote 2 in there, I have edited the initial post. Unfortunately, the network was still not learning correctly even it is 10 in there, seems like it is giving random results.

Comment: see the update; also - do not change questions on SO, but rather accept an answer and create a new one, otherwise people cannot benefit from the issue being fixed; SO is not an "iterative debugging" platform

Comment: good point with shuffling because I was wondering why it gives always last class for different images.